# What is the purpose of the Emacs function (eval-and-compile...)?

Tags: emacs, elisp

I can read the documentation, so I'm not asking for a cut-and-paste of that.

I'm trying to understand the motivation for this function.

When would I want to use it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [documentation in the Emacs lisp manual](http://www.gnu.org/s/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Eval-During-Compile.html) does have some example situations that seem to answer your question (as opposed to the doc string).

From looking at the Emacs source code, `eval-and-compile` is used to quiet the compiler, to make macros/functions available during compilation (and evaluation), or to make feature/version specific variants of macros/functions available during compilation.

One usage I found helpful to see was in [`ezimage.el`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/tree/lisp/ezimage.el).  In there, an `if` statement was put inside the `eval-and-compile` to conditionally define macros depending on whether the package was compiled/eval'ed in Emacs or XEmacs, and additionally whether a particular feature was present.  By wrapping that conditional inside the `eval-and-compile` you enable the appropriate macro usage during compilation.  A similar situation can be found in [`mwheel.el`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/tree/lisp/mwheel.el).

Similarly, if you want to define a function via `fset` and have it available during compilation, you need to have the call to `fset` wrapped with `eval-and-compile` because otherwise the symbol -> function association isn't available until the file is evaluated (because compilation of a call to `fset` just optimizes the assignment, it doesn't actually *do* the assignment).  Why would you want this assignment during compilation?  To quiet the compiler.  Note: this is just my re-wording of what is in the elisp documentation.

I did notice a lot of uses in Emacs code which just wrapped calls to `require`, which sounds redundant when you read the documentation.  I'm at a loss as to how to explain those.